# Common Lisp Create matrix from the list

Tags: common-lisp

I have: a list with lists of values ,e.g.

```
(List (list 1 2) (list 3 4 5) (list 1))
```

Note: it is 2 dimensional array, so i cant get a structure like this: `(LIST (LIST (LIST 1)))`, in other words there can be only numbers\letters inside secondary list.

I want: create a function, which will make my list have the same number of columns using nil's to fill empty fields, so if i have list from above as input, my output will be:

```
((1 2 nil nil)
(3 4  5  nil)
(1 nil nil nil))
```

I am sorry, it has to be easy, but i am novice in Lisp and functional programming.

Note: i has to use CONS and APPEND only, but (this is my main problem) CONS will put each element inside a different list and APPEND will remove all nil's.

UPD: i have done as it was said below, however i still have 1 problem

```
(DEFUN FINDMLENGTH (INPUT) 
(COND
    ((NULL INPUT) NIL)
    (T (AND
            (COND ((< MAXLENGTH (length (CAR INPUT))) (SETQ MAXLENGTH (length (CAR INPUT)))))
            (FINDMLENGTH (CDR INPUT))))))

(DEFUN MAKESQUARE (INPUT RowNumb) (prog (a))
(COND
    ((NULL INPUT) NIL)
    (T (AND
            (SETQ SqMatr (APPEND SqMatr (LIST (append (car INPUT) (make-list (- RowNumb (length (CAR INPUT))))))))
            (MAKESQUARE (CDR INPUT) RowNumb)))))
(SETQ SqMatr nil)
(SETQ MAXLENGTH 0)
```

The problem is that i am currently using global variables to pass data, can somebody clarify how can i make them return variable by them self?

Comment: Why 4 elements per inner list in your example? is it given as an input?

Comment: It is an example of what input can be, number of rows and cols is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point for your homework: you can use, for each row, the function make-list to create a list of n nil elements, where n = desired lenght - length of row you already have. This will create a list with the fill-up nils. Then you can append this to the initial row.
Example:

`(append '(1 2) (make-list (- 4 (length '(1 2))))) => (1 2 nil nil)`

Do this for each row, appending the result.